# Read USB input Raspberry pi

Tags: controller, raspberry-pi, xbox

Im attempting to read a USB Xbox controller input via Raspberry pi, and at a later date i will do the same with arduio.

I have been researching for information to do this myself but i can not find exactly what i am looking for, so im asking here.

First off.
Where is a good start?

Should i do something like plugging the device in and load up a program to read the input, then code something to interpret this input?

If so, what do i use to get the input?
What format will that information be in?

Could someone with knowledge in this subject point me in the right direction, as well as how they came across the knowledge that they are sharing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the RaspberryPi there is a thorough guide, by Christian Cawley, found here:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/useful-controller-configuration-tips-for-a-raspberry-pi-retro-gaming-centre/

As for the arduino, I haven't thought about it - perhaps someone else has some input on that.

Comment: Regarding Arduino: I found this, but I don't really consider it an answer to your question, but a relevant alternative:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Arduino-functions-with-a-USB-controller-n/
"using a program called Xpadder I can have the computer interpret controller button presses as keyboard strokes. From there, Processing can read those keystrokes and send them to the Arduino from which any number of actions can be programmed to be controlled"